# Creating Protected routes for authentication

Tags: javascript, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to create protected routing and have created a component called `Protected` which fetches the access token from the backend if user exists and displays the protected components if user exists or gets navigated to the Not logged in component. This functionality is not working as expected. For some reason I am getting current user as undefined. Is it because the protected route's `Navigate` is getting rendered even before access token gets generated and stored in localStorage?

Below is the code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Outlet, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import authService from '../services/auth.service';

function Protected() {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(undefined);
  console.log(currentUser);
  useEffect(() => {
    const user = authService.getCurrentUser();
  
    if (user) {
      setCurrentUser(user);
    }
  }, []);
  
  return (
    currentUser ? <Outlet/> : <Navigate to='/notloggedin'/>
  )
}

export default Protected
```

authService.js

```
import axios from "axios";

const API_URL = "http://localhost:3000/auth";

const signup = (email, password) => {
  try {
    return axios
      .post(API_URL + "/signup", {
        email,
        password,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        //console.log(response.data.errors);
     
        if (response.data.accessToken) {
          localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(response.data));
        }
        console.log(response.data.errors?.map((error) => console.log(error.msg)))
      return response.data;
    });
  } catch(error) {
    return error;
  }
};

const login = (email, password) => {
  return axios
    .post(API_URL + "/login", {
      email,
      password,
    })
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.data.accessToken) {
        localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(response.data));
      }
      console.log(response.data.errors?.map((error) => console.log(error.msg)))
      return response.data;
    });
};

const logout = () => {
  localStorage.removeItem("user");
};

const getCurrentUser = () => {
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
};

const authService = {
  signup,
  login,
  logout,
  getCurrentUser,
};

export default authService;
```

App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
        <Route path="/notloggedin" element={<NotLoggedIn/>} />
        
        <Route element={<Protected/>}>
          <Route path="/restaurants" element={<Food_Main />} />
          <Route path="/:food/:id" element={<Food_Detail />} />
          <Route path="/payment" element={<PaymentDetails />} />
          <Route path="/thankyou" element={<ThankYou />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial `currentUser` value is `undefined` which is also a falsey value and the `useEffect` hook runs at the end of the render cycle, so on the initial render the `Navigate` component is returned and the user is navigated off the route you are trying to protect.

Render `null` or some loading indicator while the auth status is being validated/verified.

Example:

```
function Protected() {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(undefined);

  useEffect(() => {
    const user = authService.getCurrentUser();
  
    setCurrentUser(!!user); // <-- sets to defined boolean value
  }, []);
  
  if (currentUser === undefined) {
    return null; // or loading indicator/spinner/etc...
 
  return currentUser
    ? <Outlet/>
    : <Navigate to='/notloggedin' replace />;
}
```